# Samba username mapping not working as desired

Tags: linux, unix, samba, share, mapping

I have the following username mapping in Samba:

```
master = johndoe user2 user3
regular = user5 user6
restricted = johndoe user8 user9
```

By default, Samba will **always** map `johndoe` to the last entry in username.map, that is `restricted`.

Any idea how to map `johndoe` to multiple entries? I need this, because there are some shares where not all users have access, but some users (like `johndoe`) must have access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map a user to multiple entries. Samba would take your user (johndoe) and match it to 'master' on the first line, but it wouldn't stop there, it would try the second line and then the third, where it would find 'johndoe' again and map it to 'restricted', this would replace the originally found 'master'.

You could use 'vfs_acl_xattr' and use 'setfacl' to set the permissions for users without the usermapping.